# haproxy : Limit WebSocket payload length

Tags: haproxy

My server is distributing websocket client connections over 4 local websocket servers and I need to prevent these websocket servers to get flooded with big chunks of data.

**Question:**

Is it possible to instruct haProxy to `blacklist + close` a client connection when that connection sends a big chunk of data ?

*For instance, I do not expect from a regular user more than 1024 bytes per message/payload, this could be translated in to something like no more than 5 messages per second.*